# Regarding the usage of SemaphoreSlim with Async/Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, semaphore

I am not an advanced developer. I'm just trying to get a hold on the task library and just googling. I've never used the class `SemaphoreSlim` so I would like to know what it does. Here I present code where `SemaphoreSlim` is used with `async` & `await` but which I do not understand. Could someone help me to understand the code below.

### 1st set of code

```
await WorkerMainAsync();

async Task WorkerMainAsync()
{
    SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
    while (true)
    {
        await ss.WaitAsync();
        // you should probably store this task somewhere and then await it
        var task = DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
    }
}

async Task DoPollingThenWorkAsync(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    var msg = Poll();
    if (msg != null)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); // process the I/O-bound job
    }

    // this assumes you don't have to worry about exceptions
    // otherwise consider try-finally
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Firstly, the `WorkerMainAsync` will be called and a `SemaphoreSlim` is used. Why is `10` passed to the constructor of `SemaphoreSlim`?

When does the control come out of the `while` loop again?

What does `ss.WaitAsync();` do?

The `DoPollingThenWorkAsync()` function is expecting a `SemaphoreSlim` but is not passed anything when it is called. Is this typo?

Why is `await Task.Delay(3000);` used?

They could simply use `Task.Delay(3000)` but why do they use `await` here instead?

### 2nd set of code for same purpose

```
async Task WorkerMainAsync()
{
    SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
    List<Task> trackedTasks = new List<Task>();
    while (DoMore())
    {
        await ss.WaitAsync();
        trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => 
        {
            DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
            ss.Release();
        }));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
}

void DoPollingThenWorkAsync()
{
    var msg = Poll();
    if (msg != null)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // process the long running CPU-bound job
    }
}
```

Here is a task & `ss.Release` added to a list.  I really do not understand how tasks can run after adding to a list?

```
trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => 
{
    await DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
    ss.Release();
}));
```

I am looking forward for a good explanation & help to understand the two sets of code. Thanks

Comment: "here task & ss.release is added to list" -> "trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(" has 2 pieces. 1 = "Add something to the list" => trackedTasks.Add( , 2 = "Start a new task" ->Task.Run.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> why 10 is passing to SemaphoreSlim constructor.

They are using `SemaphoreSlim` to limit to 10 tasks at a time. The semaphore is "taken" before each task is started, and each task "releases" it when it finishes. For more about semaphores, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> they can use simply Task.Delay(3000) but why they use await here.

`Task.Delay` creates a task that completes after the specified time interval and returns it. Like most `Task`-returning methods, `Task.Delay` returns immediately; it is the returned `Task` that has the delay. So if the code did not `await` it, there would be no delay.

> just really do not understand after adding task to list how they can run?

In the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Task` objects are returned "hot". This means they're already running by the time they're returned. The `await Task.WhenAll` at the end is waiting for them all to complete.

Comment: why Task.Delay return immediately rather as name implies delay() then it should make some delay()...isn't ?

Comment: what is the difference between Semaphore & SemaphoreSlim classes? can u plzz redirect me to a best url from where i can read & see the code about various usage of TPL library. thanks

Comment: please see my first set of code. there u see DoPollingThenWorkAsync() function is getting call from WorkerMainAsync() function but no SemaphoreSlim instance is getting pass to DoPollingThenWorkAsync(). is it a mistake or typo ?

Comment: As the name implies, `Task.Delay` returns a task representing a delay. The difference between `Semaphore` and `SemaphoreSlim` is covered in the [same MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The first code sample has a typo; it should be passing the `SemaphoreSlim` instance to the worker method.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Could you please include your comment above in your answer. (I tried an edit but it has been declined.)

Comment: @participant: I think it is good as-is. The answer answers the question, and the comments answer the additional questions asked in the comments.