# Linq calling task.Run accessing wrong member, deferred execution issue?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, lambda, task

I'm having a weird issue with a linq query using the wrong values.  My code looks like this

```
await Task.WhenAll((from item in itemsToProcess
    let taskCount = count++
    select Task.Run(() => { process(item).Result; }))
    .AsParallel().ToArray());
```

Basically I have a list of 50k items that are getting called into a method that makes a web call.  They are completely unrelated, can run in any order, and don't access anything shared.  BUT, once in awhile, very randomly, it seems to pass the wrong item to the process method like you would encounter in a foreach loop if you didn't copy it to a local variable.

If I change my code to this

```
await Task.WhenAll((from item in itemsToProcess
    let taskCount = count++
    let itemCopy = item
    select Task.Run(() => { process(itemCopy).Result; }))
    .AsParallel().ToArray());
```

Then I don't seem to have this issue.  So my question is, am I missing something, or is this expected behavior?  I thought that the from clause of linq was supposed to copy to a local copy, but is that not the case?  I'm having a hard time finding anything that addresses this directly.  But I see plenty of examples of calling async methods inside a linq expression without doing the extra let.

I've also tried making the lambda async and awaiting the method, but then I run into no a threads situations.  Maybe there is a completely better way of doing this?  I would be happy to know about it.  In a nutshell, all I'm doing is iterating a list and calling a method in parallel because it is I/O bound and not cpu bound.  The other possibility is that there is tons of posts already about this, and I'm just searching for the wrong terminology.  If so, I would be happy to know that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel and asynchronous code rarely should be used together. Parallel is ideally just for CPU-bound code.

Why can't you just do this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(itemsToProcess.Select(item => process(item)));
```

**Edit based on comments**:

Asynchronous throttling is (somewhat) easily done by using `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
static SemaphoreSlim throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(50);
static async Task ProcessAsync(Item item)
{
  await throttle.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    ... // Original process(item) code
  }
  finally
  {
    throttle.Release();
  }
}
```

This will throttle the item processing to 50. This is just a number I pulled out of the air; you should experiment with it a bit to find an appropriate value.

Note that the parallel processing throttling stopped working as soon as the work became asynchronous. Asynchronous work doesn't "take up" a thread, so it doesn't count against the parallel processing throttling (or thread pool injection rate throttling).

Comment: This is a GREAT question, and I would love to figure out how to get rid of the parallel calls.  This project started out completely parallel, and I decided to redo it asynchronous, but I'm very new to asynchronous, so I'm running into some issues.  When I do this, it literally runs every single call in parallel at the same time, which causes timeouts in my web calls as there's just to many at once.  Using the task pool it limits the tasks to a certain number running at once and pools them.  If there's a way to use the purely async call and have them pooled that would be ideal I would think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998779/regarding-the-usage-of-semaphoreslim-with-async-await Your comment made this come up in the related links, looks like what I probably need, thanks!

Comment: This seems to do the trick nicely!  You have been extremely helpful.  I have a lot of testing to do now, but this seems to be working great with much less overhead without the tasks, and without skipping iterations.